# Parsing a custom function for overlapping community clusters igraph

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I'm trying to apply an overlapping community clustering algorithm to some igraph networks. I found a custom function for one [here](http://igraph.wikidot.com/community-detection-in-r#toc0). This is it:

```
clique.community <- function(graph, k) {
   clq <- cliques(graph, min=k, max=k)
   edges <- c()
   for (i in seq_along(clq)) {
     for (j in seq_along(clq)) {
       if ( length(unique(c(clq[[i]], clq[[j]]))) == k+1 ) {
         edges <- c(edges, c(i,j)-1)
       }
     }
   }
   clq.graph <- simplify(graph(edges))
   V(clq.graph)$name <- seq_len(vcount(clq.graph))
   comps <- decompose.graph(clq.graph)

   lapply(comps, function(x) {
     unique(unlist(clq[ V(x)$name ]))
   })
}
```

You can try using it on a randomly generated network for testing if you would like. I have limited experience with custom functions and do not understand what the `k` argument is for and what to put in it. I would greatly appreciate someone explaining it to me and what type of object it is asking for input.

Comment: k is the size of the complete subgraphs.

Comment: @crestor does that mean I'm specifying how large I want the clusters it finds?